# How to enable Perl features via command line?

Tags: perl

I want to enable `say` feature (but also all the others). I know that if I write the code on the command line, I can use `-E` option instead of `-e`. But if I am running a script:

```
perl script.pl
```

I cannot use `-E`. I don't want to put `use feature say` in the script; I want to use command line option. What kind of option can I use here? I have not been able to figure this out from the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#AVAILABLE-FEATURES).

Comment: If you don't want to change the script or use command-line options you're going to have to use PERLOPT (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#ENVIRONMENT). Can you explain why -E isn't acceptable.

Comment: 1) I *wan't* to use command line options - I was asking for them! Is that unclear from my question? 2) You cannot do `perl -E script.pl`.

Comment: Ah! I see. I thought you couldn't modify the command line (because it was in a script or some such). See amon's answer then.

Comment: This whole question is a mistake.  If a script depends on certain features, it should say so in the script, not depend on you to supply the right command line options.

Comment: @Tomas, Why??? A script that doesn't run unless the caller puts a part of it on the command line makes no sense!

Comment: Why don't you want to put `use feature 'say';` or `use v5.10.0` in your script?

Comment: Do I have to justify anything I ask, why I ask, why I need it etc.? I am just interested in how it's done via command line and wanted to avoid obvious "use feature say" answer, that's all!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can import a module with the `-M` switch. In general,

```
-MFoo=bar,baz
```

is equivalent to

```
use Foo (split /,/ 'bar,baz');
```

So here, we would do `-Mfeature=say` or load a feature bundle like `-M5.010`.

However, I'd recommend specifying any features you use inside the script itself. This will avoid confusing errors when you forget to specify the switch.

Answer (score 1):

I made a bash alias:

```bash
alias sperl='perl -Mfeature=say'
```

now I can do stuff like

```bash
~/perl$ sperl -e "say 'hi'"
hi
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the featured `say` in command line for a *one liner*:

```
perl -Mfeature=say -e 'say "ok"'
```

## Output

```
ok
```

(with newline)